# p:layout content not shown with HTML element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.2. The content of my layout is not displayed if I use an HTML element inside this layout as you can see in the image below. If I put the HTML element outside of the layout, then everything works.

[image: content not displayed with html element]

***left***: without `<h1>` element / **right**: with `<h1>` element

Did I overlook something or is there a reason for this behavior? I'm quite new to JSF.

---

**Code**

*content of `<h:body>`*

```
<h:form style="max-width:1000px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="1">
        <p:menuitem value="Rechnung" icon="ui-icon-home" url="index.xhtml" />
        <p:menuitem value="Bearbeiten" icon="ui-icon-pencil" url="editor.xhtml" />
    </p:tabMenu>
</h:form>

<p:layout style="max-width:1000px;">
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border: none;">
        <p:layout style="border: none;">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="250" style="border: none;">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Tabellen">
                            <!-- some <p:menuitem> -->
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border: none;">
                <h1>Testresult</h1> <-- don't work
                <p:outputLabel value="test text"/> <-- works
                <!-- table -->
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Comment: What does the browser console and source tell you?

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. But I just saw that the source code contains all elements but they aren't displayed because the height of the layout `<div>` is 0px.

Comment: have you tried putting the p:layout inside a form and see what happens

Comment: that didn't solve the problem. :/

Answer (score 1):

When i talked to Cagatay Civici during a JSF class, he recommended us not to use layouts(p or pe) and instead use regular divs to manage layouts. Nested layouts were definitely not recommended.

So our layout page went from

```
 <pe:layout fullPage="true" id="layoutFull">


        <pe:layoutPane id="idar758" position="north" closable="false" collapsible="false" size="60"
            collapsed="false" resizable="false">
            <h:form id="postLoginHeader">
                <ui:include src="./loginHeader.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
        </pe:layoutPane>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" closable="false" collapsible="false"
            collapsed="false" resizable="false" resizeWhileDragging="false"
            id="centerLayout">
            <div id="idar759" class="slimScrollMyPage1">
                <h:panelGrid id="panelGroup_38" columns="1" width="100%">
                    <p:messages globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" id="messages"
                        rendered="true" closable="true">
                        <p:effect id="idar760" type="bounce" event="load" delay="500" />
                    </p:messages>
                    <ui:insert name="body" id="insert_38" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <pe:layoutPane id="idar761" position="west" closable="true" resizable="false"
            resizeWhileDragging="false" size="235">
            <div id="idar762" class="slimScroll">
                <ui:include src="leftMenuAdmin.xhtml" id="include_36" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <p:spacer height="5" />
        </pe:layoutPane>

        <pe:layoutPane id="idar763" position="south" closable="false" size="30">
            <h:panelGroup id="panelGroup_40south">
                <ui:include src="./footer.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </pe:layoutPane>
    </pe:layout>
```

to

```
<ui:include src="./adminPostLoginHeader.xhtml" />
    <div class="container" id="div_23">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelGrid_34"
            columnClasses="layoutColumn1,layoutColumn2">
            <h:panelGroup id="panelGroup_35">
                <div class="collapsible">
                    <p:commandButton value=" " />
                    <div id="idar762" class="slimScroll">
                        <ui:include src="leftMenuAdmin.xhtml" id="include_36" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="panelGroup_37" width="100%">
                <div id="idar759" class="slimScrollMyPage1 bckgroundDiv"
                    style="background-image: url(#{serverThemeBean.landingImageUrl}) !important;">
                    <h:panelGrid id="panelGroup_38" columns="1" width="100%">
                        <p:messages globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" id="messages"
                            rendered="true" closable="true">
                            <p:effect id="idar760" type="bounce" event="load" delay="500" />
                        </p:messages>
                        <ui:insert name="body" id="insert_38" />
                        <p style="padding-bottom: 5px;" id="p_39" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </div>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <ui:include src="./adminPostLoginFooter.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe the use of regular `<div>` would solve the problem but I wait to see if there is a solution with `<p:layout>` so I don't have to change the whole code.

Comment: I did not have enough reputation to add comment to your question. what happens when u  add the h1 inside a panelGroup

Comment: Care needs to be exercised while using `<h:panelGroup>` for layout which renders an inline HTML element `<span>` unless `layout` is set to `block` (`<h:panelGroup layout="block">`) in which case it renders a block level element `<div>` (when `style` and/or `styleClass` attributes are present).